# First order and infinitesimal deformations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

**Terminology**. Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over some algebraically closed field $k$. By an *infinitesimal* deformation of $X$, I mean a flat surjective map $\mathfrak X\to S=\textrm{Spec }A$, where $A$ is a local Artin $k$-algebra, such that $X$ is isomorphic to the closed fiber of this map. An isomorphism of deformations is an $S$-isomorphism between the total spaces, compatible with the inclusions of $X$ inside them. By a *trivial* deformation, I mean a deformation which is isomorphic to the product deformation $X\times \textrm{Spec }A\to \textrm{Spec }A$.

An algebraic variety $X$ is said to be *rigid* if it has no nontrivial infinitesimal deformations. One can show that if $X$ is nonsingular, then it is rigid of and only if $H^1(X,T_X)=0$, where $T_X$ is tha tangent bundle.

But $H^1(X,T_X)$ parameterizes, for any nonsingular $X$, isomorphism classes of *first order* deformations of $X$: those deformations defined over the dual numbers $D=k[t]/t^2$.

So, *a posteriori*, there should be something special in nonsingular varieties: if they have no nontrivial first order deformations, they have no infinitesimal deformations at all.

**Question**: can you show me an example of a (necessarily singular) variety with no nontrivial deformation over $D$, but with a nontrivial deformation over some other local Artin ring $A$?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe William Lang's examples (they are nonsingular surfaces) should work, but one needs to think carefully about the relation between $W_2$ and $D$. Check out: http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=CM_1995__97_1-2_157_0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question! Here is my take on it.

The nonsingularity hypothesis is a simplification rather than a true necessity. If $X$ is nonsingular, then every first-order family is locally trivial, thus, by the Kodaira-Spencer equivalence the set of *all* first-order families for $X$ is parametrized by $H^1(X, \mathscr T_X)$. Moreover, the obstruction calculus is simplified, since the set of (small) liftings of a family for $X$ has a transitive $H^1(X,\mathscr T_X)$-action, which Sernesi takes advantage of to prove this theorem.

In the general case, not all first-order families for $X$ are locally trivial, and this is captured in the following comparison sequence:
$$0\to H^1(X,\mathscr T_X)\to \mathsf D_X(D)\to H^0(X,\mathscr T^1_X)\to H^2(X,\mathscr T_X)$$
where I've denoted the set of all first-order families for $X$ by $\mathsf D_X(D)$. In fact, Hartshorne's "Deformation Theory" extends this comparison sequence to the following sequence, for any local artinian ring $R$, useful for this lifting problem (Thm 10.2(b)):
$$0\to H^1(X,\mathscr T_X)\to \mathsf E(\mathcal X/R)\to H^0(X,\mathscr T^1_X)\to H^2(X,\mathscr T_X)$$
where $\mathsf E(\mathcal X/R)$ is the set of liftings of a chosen family $\mathcal X\to\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ for $X$ (actually, his version is slightly more general than this). Since $\mathscr T^1_X$ is supported on the singular locus of $X$, the nonsingularity hypothesis above simply ensures that $\mathscr T^1_X = 0$, so that $H^1(X,\mathscr T_X) = \mathsf E(\mathcal X/R)$. Thus, $X$ is rigid iff $H^1(X,\mathscr T_X)=0$ since all liftings are trivial, which is what Sernesi's proof boils down to. However in the general case, the theorem is something like the following:

$X$ is rigid iff $H^1(X,\mathscr T_X)=0$ and the obstruction map $H^0(X,\mathscr T^1_X)\to H^2(X,\mathscr T_X)$ is injective.

Now to answer your question. Suppose that $X$ has no nontrivial family over $D$. This means that $\mathsf D_X(D)=0$. By the first-order comparison sequence, this says exactly that $H^1(X,\mathscr T_X) = 0$ and $H^0(X,\mathscr T^1_X)\to H^2(X,\mathscr T_X)$ is injective, so that there is never a nontrivial lifting of any family for $X$ over any artinian local ring. Thus, $X$ is rigid.

Comment: Ah. I think I see my issue from before. "Rigid" means there exists a deformation over $D$ and the trivial one is the only one, i.e. we don't use the term rigid to mean "there exists at most one deformation over D"

Comment: Dear @Matt, I think that's right... there always exists the trivial deformation, but given an arbitrary infinitesimal family, we may not be able to extend it, depending on the associated obstruction. So yes, by rigid we mean there exists a unique family over any local artinian ring with residue field $k$, namely the trivial one (up to isomorphism of course).

Comment: Well, I don't think there is always the trivial deformation. There might not be any $\mathfrak{X}/A$ such that the special fiber is $X$ (even if $X$ is smooth).

Comment: Dear @Matt, that is not correct. There is always the product family. It is possible that there are some hypotheses I'm taking for granted, but this is explicitly stated e.g. on p. 21 of Sernesi's book.

Comment: Ah. I totally missed the hypothesis that $A$ must be a $k$-algebra, because the only cases I ever consider this is not the case. In general deformation setups where you don't make this assumption (as in asking whether or not $X$ lifts from characteristic $p$ to characteristic $0$) then there might not be a trivial deformation, as is the case in the link I posted above.

Comment: Dear @Matt, that's interesting. I always think about the case where $A$ is a f.g. $k$-algebra with residue field $k$, so I haven't run into this before. Glad to be aware of it for future reference! Cheers

Comment: @Andrew: This is a great answer. Thanks for your clarity. So the key point seems to be that when $X$ is nonsingular, $H^1(T_X)=E(\mathcal X/R)$, for *any* $\mathcal X/R$. Knowing this, it is clear that the $H^1$ vanishes iff $X$ is rigid. I only regret I do not have Hartshorne's book, so I do know anything about the maps in the sequences you mention. Also, when you say "liftings" (elements in $E(\mathcal X/R)$), what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Dear @Brenin, by *lifting* I mean specifically a lifting over a *small extension* $0\to(t)\to\tilde A\to A\to 0$ of $A$, as in Sernesi p. 32. Actually, the first version of the comparison sequence is in Sernesi's book too, p. 65. I got Hartshorne's book from Springerlink -- it's quite cheap if you have access through a uni network.